# Split column on delimiter to new rows in groups of two

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Here is an example df, I’m trying to split on ‘>’ in column ‘path’ and make new rows. I want to have each row contain 2 values example below.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'path': ['SPAM>EGGS>BACON>HAM', 'SPAM>EGGS>HAM', 'SPAM>EGGS>HAM', 'SPAM>HAM'],
    'arrival_time': ['2/4/23 20:30', '2/5/23 2:24', '2/5/23 0:28', '2/3/23 0:28'],
    'departure_time': ['2/4/23 22:00', '2/5/23 2:54', '2/5/23 1:28', '2/3/23 1:28']
})
```

Expected

```
         path  arrival_time departure_time
0   SPAM>EGGS  2/4/23 20:30   2/4/23 22:00
1  EGGS>BACON  2/4/23 20:30   2/4/23 22:00
2   BACON>HAM  2/4/23 20:30   2/4/23 22:00
3   SPAM>EGGS   2/5/23 2:24    2/5/23 2:54
4    EGGS>HAM   2/5/23 2:24    2/5/23 2:54
5   SPAM>EGGS   2/5/23 0:28    2/5/23 1:28
6    EGGS>HAM   2/5/23 0:28    2/5/23 1:28
7    SPAM>HAM   2/3/23 0:28    2/3/23 1:28
```

I used split but can’t figure out how to get groups of 2.

```
df['path'] = df['path'].str.split(pat='>').explode('path')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.split() on pattern ">" and .apply() a lambda by zipping the list indexes into pairs. Wrap in a list comp to create list of str pairs. Finally .explode() the lists to new rows and .reset_index() to clean up index numbers.

```
df = df.assign(
    path=df["path"].str.split(pat=">")
    .apply(lambda x: [f"{v[0]}>{v[1]}" for v in zip(x[:-1], x[1:])])
).explode("path").reset_index(drop=True)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
         path  arrival_time departure_time
0   SPAM>EGGS  2/4/23 20:30   2/4/23 22:00
1  EGGS>BACON  2/4/23 20:30   2/4/23 22:00
2   BACON>HAM  2/4/23 20:30   2/4/23 22:00
3   SPAM>EGGS   2/5/23 2:24    2/5/23 2:54
4    EGGS>HAM   2/5/23 2:24    2/5/23 2:54
5   SPAM>EGGS   2/5/23 0:28    2/5/23 1:28
6    EGGS>HAM   2/5/23 0:28    2/5/23 1:28
7    SPAM>HAM   2/3/23 0:28    2/3/23 1:28
```

Answer (score 0):

First add splitted column back to DataFrame by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html), so possible use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html), the add shifted values per groups to `path` by [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) and [`Series.str.cat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html), last remove rows with missing values in `path` by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and create default `RangeIndex`:

```
df1 = df.assign(path = df['path'].str.split(pat='>')).explode('path')

df1['path'] = df1['path'].str.cat(df1.groupby(level=0)['path'].shift(-1), sep='>')
df1 = df1.dropna(subset=['path']).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df1)
         path  arrival_time departure_time
0   SPAM>EGGS  2/4/23 20:30   2/4/23 22:00
1  EGGS>BACON  2/4/23 20:30   2/4/23 22:00
2   BACON>HAM  2/4/23 20:30   2/4/23 22:00
3   SPAM>EGGS   2/5/23 2:24    2/5/23 2:54
4    EGGS>HAM   2/5/23 2:24    2/5/23 2:54
5   SPAM>EGGS   2/5/23 0:28    2/5/23 1:28
6    EGGS>HAM   2/5/23 0:28    2/5/23 1:28
7    SPAM>HAM   2/3/23 0:28    2/3/23 1:28
```